# Python File Renaming

Tags: python

I have some files in a directory,

file_IL.txt
file_IL.csv
file_NY.txt
file_NY.csv

I will have to rename them so that they get a sequence number. For example,

file_IL.txt_001
file_IL.csv_001
file_NY.txt_002
file_NY.csv_002

I have written the following Python code

```
def __init__(self):  

    self.indir = "C:\Files"  



def __call__(self):  

    found = glob.glob(self.indir + '/file*')  

    length = len(glob.glob(self.indir + '/file*'))  
    print length  
    count = 000  

    for num in (glob.glob(self.indir + '/file*')):  
        count = count + 1  
        count = str(count)  
        print count  
        shutil.copy(num, num+'_'+count)  
        print num  
        count = int(count)
```

But this is giving me a result as below,

file_IL.txt_001
file_IL.csv_002
file_NY.txt_003
file_NY.csv_004

Can someone help me modify the above Python script to match my requirements? I'm new to Python and I'm not sure how can one implement it.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to store the extension and count for that extension in a dictionary.

```
def __call__(self):  

    found = glob.glob(self.indir + '/file*')  
    length = len(found)  
    counts = {}

    for num in found:
        ext = num.rsplit(".",1)[-1]    # Right split to get the extension
        count = counts.get(ext,0) + 1  # get the count, or the default of 0 and add 1
        shutil.copy(num, num+'_'+'%03d' % count)   # Fill to 3 zeros
        counts[ext] = count            # Store the new count
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one error, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Can you please tell me how to fix that? It's at the count=counts.get(ext,0)+1

Comment: @user1345260 Fixed. Just needed to pull the extension correctly, and not cast `count` to a string.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: `length = len(found)`, rather than duplicating the glob call, yes?

Comment: @Edward Yeah, you could do that. I duplicated the OPs code for the most part and focused on just getting the re-numbering working. Actually, `found` isn't even used in the code. I've fixed the code, but left `found` in as it might be useful to the OP.

Comment: I recommend `ext = os.path.splitext(num)[1]`