# Renaming files of the samekind via Python

Tags: python

I have some files in a directory,

file_IL.txt
file_IL.csv
file_NY.txt
file_NY.csv

I will have to rename them so that they get a sequence number. For example,

file_IL.txt_001
file_IL.csv_001
file_NY.txt_002
file_NY.csv_002

I have written the following Python code

```
def __init__(self):  

    self.indir = "C:\Files" 

def __call__(self):  

    found = glob.glob(self.indir + '/file*')  
    length = len(found)  
    counts = {}

    for num in found:
        ext = num.rsplit(".",1)[-1]    # Right split to get the extension
        count = counts.get(ext,0) + 1  # get the count, or the default of 0 and add 1
        shutil.copy(num, num+'_'+'%03d' % count)   # Fill to 3 zeros
        counts[ext] = count            # Store the new count
```

This works at times but then at times it throws a result as below,

file_IL.txt_001
file_IL.csv_002
file_NY.txt_002
file_NY.csv_001

What I want is the files of the same kind even though they have different extension to have the same count. I'm kind of lost now, can someone please help me out?

Comment: Why are using `shutil.copy` instead of `os.rename`?

Comment: Because I'm not supposed to overwrite the files. I'm supposed to keep the file from each stage

Comment: Perhaps ``glob()`` is not guaranteed to return a list sorted by file name.

Comment: You posted the same question before: [Python File Renaming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624568/python-file-renaming). Why don't you respond to the responses you already got?

Comment: When are you gettin those errors? Or randomly?

Comment: How do you tell whether 2 files are same kind?

Comment: I'm getting those errors randomly.

Also, I can figure out the files are of same kind by the first part of the file name. For example: file_IL. It has two types. txt and .csv

Comment: You explicitly initialize the count for each ext to zero, `count = counts.get(ext,0) + 1 `

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a nOOb for this.

Comment: I'm getting the desired results. I just changed this line: `found = glob.glob(self.indir + '/*.*')`, but I don't think there is the error.

Comment: I won't be able to do *.* as there are other files also in that directory

Answer (score 1):

The output of `glob.glob()` is unordered. Sort the file names if you want them to be numbered in lexicographical order:

```
for num in sorted(found):
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
a=["file_IL.txt", "file_IL.csv","file_NY.txt","file_NY.csv"]
#split by dot
b = sorted([i.split('.') for i in a])

i=0
c=1

#loop through b
while i<len(b)-1:
    #start at the current index (i)
    for j in range(i, len(b)):
        #Check if file name of the current element (b[j][0]) is equal to 
        #the file name that you started with (b[i][0]).
        #If so, rename the file, else break
        if b[i][0]==b[j][0]:
            print "%s.%s%03d"%(b[j][0], b[j][1], c)
        else:
            break
    #increment your counter
    c+=1
    #increase i to the index of the file name that is not equal to the one that
    #you started with
    i=j
```

It's easy to modify this code for what you need.

Comment: Easy to modify, but what about easy to understand?

Comment: @Christian I don't really see the problem. Could you point out what is difficult to understand so I can explain it?

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like this.

```
filenames =['file_IL.txt', 'file_IL.csv',
            'file_NY.txt', 'file_NY.csv']
extensions = {b:[] for b in set([x.split('.')[0] for x in filenames])}
newnames = []

for fname in filenames:
    extensions[fname.split('.')[0]].append(fname)

for i,fnames in enumerate(extensions.values()):
    for fname in fnames:
        newnames.append('{0}_{1:03d}'.format(fname, i))
```